# MsSQL Fetching Data based on Previous and Current value in ZicZac way

Tags: sql-server

My Table has

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|RunningId  PreviousValue CurrentValue CreatedDate  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|1           1000            1001        2018-04-20  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|2           1001            1002        2018-04-21  | 
----------------------------------------------------------
|3           1002            1003        2018-04-22  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|4           2000            2003        2018-04-22  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|5           2003            2004        2018-04-23  |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

If I search for `1002`, query should return previous and current value from the begining
Eg:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
PreValue   CurrrentValue:
----------------------------------------------------------
1000       1001
----------------------------------------------------------
1001       1002
----------------------------------------------------------
1002       1003
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to take the reference in ZicZac way. If I search for 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, all the result should return row# 1,2 & 3. 
Same way if I search for 2000, 2003, 2004, it should return row# 4,5. And the values are random. not in sequence way. 
First row have some value in the beginning, then it changed to some other value, then changed to some other value and so on. so Pair can be[pre-cur value], 1-3, 3-7, 7-2, 2-100.... If I search for 7, it should return both way 1,3,7,2,100

How to query this?

Comment: Use a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this recursive query. It can be optimized a little, but will give you the basic idea of how to link each relationship.

```
DECLARE @ValueToFind INT = 1002

;WITH ForwardRelationships AS
(
    SELECT
        SourceValue = @ValueToFind,
        CurrentValue = I.CurrentValue,
        PreviousValue = I.PreviousValue
    FROM
        IDs AS I
    WHERE
        I.CurrentValue = @ValueToFind OR I.PreviousValue = @ValueToFind

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        SourceValue = F.SourceValue,
        CurrentValue = I.CurrentValue,
        PreviousValue = I.PreviousValue
    FROM
        ForwardRelationships AS F -- We are referencing the CTE that we are declaring (recursively)
        INNER JOIN IDs AS I ON F.CurrentValue = I.PreviousValue
),
BackwardRelationships AS
(
    SELECT
        SourceValue = @ValueToFind,
        CurrentValue = I.CurrentValue,
        PreviousValue = I.PreviousValue
    FROM
        IDs AS I
    WHERE
        I.CurrentValue = @ValueToFind OR I.PreviousValue = @ValueToFind

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        SourceValue = F.SourceValue,
        CurrentValue = I.CurrentValue,
        PreviousValue = I.PreviousValue
    FROM
        BackwardRelationships AS F
        INNER JOIN IDs AS I ON F.PreviousValue = I.CurrentValue
)
SELECT
    F.PreviousValue,
    F.CurrentValue
FROM
    ForwardRelationships AS F
UNION
SELECT
    B.PreviousValue,
    B.CurrentValue
FROM
    BackwardRelationships AS B
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 30000)
```

Comment: It works for sample scenario, will try with real time and post you back, if need any help. THANKS A LOT EzLo....

Answer (score 1):

this will solve your problem

```
select Prevalue, CurrentValue FROM Table1 WHERE Prevalue = 1002 or
CurrentValue = 1002 or  CurrentValue = (Select Prevalue  from Table1
where CurrentValue = 1002 ) ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi. it works for 1002, but not for 1003. I want to take the reference in ZicZac way. If I search for 1001, 1002, 1003, all the result should return row# 1,2 & 3. Same way if I search for 2001, it should return row# 4,5.  And the values are random. not in sequence way. First row have some value in the beginning, then it changed to some other value, then changed to some other value and so on. so Pair can be[pre-cur value], 1-3, 3-7, 7-2, 2-100.... If I search for 7, it should return both way 1,3,7,2,100. Am I clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get all the values from the table, prior to 1002, assuming you want from the beginning.

```
select Prevalue, CurrentValue
FROM MyTable
WHERE id <=
(SELECT Id from MyTable 
WHERE PreValue = 1002)
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use row_number() function to get your desired results.

```
create table t (RunningId int,PreviousValue int,CurrentValue int,CreatedDate date)

;
insert into t values
(1, 1000, 1001,  '04-20-2018')
,(2, 1001, 1002, '04-21-2018')
,(3, 1002, 1003, '04-22-2018')
,(4, 2000, 2003, '04-22-2018')
,(5, 2003, 2004, '04-23-2018');

; with cte as (
select *,r=row_number() over (order by runningid asc) from
t
    )

select c1.* from cte c1 join cte
c2 on c1.r<=c2.r and c2.previousvalue=1002
```

Also if your RunningId values are always increasing then you don't need row_number and simple self join will work  like below

```
select t1.*
from t t1
join t t2 
on t1.RunningId<=t2.RunningId and t2.previousvalue=1002
```

Comment: Thanks Dhruv, Thanks Ravi. it works for 1002, but not for 1003. I want to take the reference in ZicZac way. If I search for 1001, 1002, 1003, all the result should return row# 1,2 & 3. Same way if I search for 2001, it should return row# 4,5. And the values are random. not in sequence way. First row have some value in the beginning, then it changed to some other value, then changed to some other value and so on. so Pair can be[pre-cur value], 1-3, 3-7, 7-2, 2-100.... If I search for 7, it should return both way 1,3,7,2,100.    Here I can use runningId and Date for sorting purpose. Am I clear?

Comment: Dhruvu, CTE is working for 1001,1002 and not for 1003